# Implicitly code-splitting with webpack, bundle-loader react-router

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router

**Edit2:** Edited the regex to match window's file paths and the code splitting is now happening. But my children components to my root route still won't load.

**Edit:** My code has changed since last week, but I'm still stuck on that problem (and I need to declare my routes in a declarative way, so using JSX).

First of all, I'm using Webpack 1.x with React, react-router, bundle-loader, Babel6, ES6 and airbnb-eslint-config.

I tried following [Henley Edition's article](http://henleyedition.com/implicit-code-splitting-with-react-router-and-webpack/) about code-splitting and loading chunks (with its [example repo](https://github.com/echenley/react-router-huge-apps-refactor)), based on [React's huge app example](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/tree/master/examples/huge-apps).

But I couldn't manage to make [bundle-loader](https://github.com/webpack/bundle-loader) split my code into chunks...

Here's my code :

**webpack.config.js**

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

const nodeDir = `${__dirname}/node_modules`;

const routeComponentRegex = /src[\/\\]views[\/\\]([^\/\\]+)[\/\\]js[\/\\]([^\/\\]+).js$/;
const paths = [ // Only to test which files match the regex, juste in case
  'src/views/index/js/Index.js',
  'src/views/login-page/js/LoginForm.js',
  'src/common/main-content/js/MainContent.js',
  'src/routes/main.js',
];

console.log(routeComponentRegex.test(paths[0])); // prints 'true'
console.log(routeComponentRegex.test(paths[1])); // prints 'true'
console.log(routeComponentRegex.test(paths[2])); // prints 'false'
console.log(routeComponentRegex.test(paths[3])); // prints 'false'

const config = {
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      react: `${nodeDir}/react`,
      'react-dom': `${nodeDir}/react-dom`,
      'react-router': `${nodeDir}/react-router`,
      'react-fetch': `${nodeDir}/react-fetch`,
      'react-cookie': `${nodeDir}/react-cookie`,
      'react-bootstrap': `${nodeDir}/react-bootstrap`,
      'react-bootstrap-daterangepicker': `${nodeDir}/react-bootstrap-daterangepicker`,
      'react-bootstrap-datetimepicker': `${nodeDir}/react-bootstrap-datetimepicker`,
      velocity: `${nodeDir}/velocity-animate`,
      moment: `${nodeDir}/moment`,
      slimscroll: `${nodeDir}/slimscroll`,
    },
  },
  entry: {
    app: './client/src/routes/js/main',
    vendors: [
      'react', 'react-dom',
      'react-router', 'react-fetch', 'react-cookie',
      'react-bootstrap', 'react-bootstrap-daterangepicker', 'react-bootstrap-datetimepicker',
      'velocity', 'moment', 'slimscroll',
    ],
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'public/dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename: 'bundles/[name].bundle.js',
    chunkFilename: 'chunks/[name].chunk.js',
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: path.join(__dirname, 'client'),
        exclude: routeComponentRegex,
        loader: 'babel',
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        include: path.join(__dirname, 'client'),
        exclude: routeComponentRegex,
        loader: 'style!css-loader?modules&importLoaders=1' +
        '&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
      },
      {
        test: routeComponentRegex,
        include: path.join(__dirname, 'client'),
        loaders: ['bundle?lazy', 'babel'],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('vendors', 'bundles/vendors.js', Infinity),
  ],
};

module.exports = config;
```

**client/src/views/main-content/js/MainContent.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';

const MainContent = (props) => (
    <div>
      <h1>App</h1>
      <ul>
        <li><Link to="/login">Login</Link></li>
      </ul>
      {props.children}
    </div>
);

MainContent.propTypes = {
  children: React.PropTypes.node.isRequired,
};

export default MainContent;
```

**public/src/views/index/js/Index.js**

```
import React from 'react';

const Index = () => (
    <h2>Index Page</h2>
);

export default Index;
```

**public/src/views/login/js/Login.js**

```
import React from 'react';

const LoginForm = () => (
  <div className="box box-default">
    <h2>Login Page</h2>
  </div>
);

export default LoginForm;
```

**Entry point (client/src/routes/main.js) :**

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, browserHistory } from 'react-router';

import MainContent from '../../common/main-content/js/MainContent';

// modules supposed to be loaded lazily
import Index from '../../views/index/js/Index';
import Login from '../../views/login/js/Login';
import ShortOffers from '../../views/short-offers/js/ShortOffers';
import CreateJobOffer from '../../views/create-job-offer/js/CreateJobOffer';

function lazyLoadComponent(lazyModule) {
  return (location, cb) => {
    lazyModule(module => {
      cb(null, module);
    });
  };
}

function lazyLoadComponents(lazyModules) {
  return (location, cb) => {
    const moduleKeys = Object.keys(lazyModules);
    const promises = moduleKeys.map(key =>
      new Promise(resolve => lazyModules[key](resolve))
    );

    Promise.all(promises).then(modules => {
      cb(null, modules.reduce((obj, module, i) => {
        obj[moduleKeys[i]] = module;
        return obj;
      }, {}));
    });
  };
}

render((
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={MainContent}>
      <IndexRoute getComponent={lazyLoadComponent(Index)} />
      <Route path="short-offers" getComponent={lazyLoadComponent(ShortOffers)} />
      <Route path="create-job-offer" getComponent={lazyLoadComponent(CreateJobOffer)} />
    </Route>
    <Route path="login" getComponent={lazyLoadComponent(Login)} />
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('content'));
```

Now `webpack`'s output :

```
Hash: a885854f956aa8d2a00c
Version: webpack 1.13.0
Time: 6321ms
                Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
bundles/app.bundle.js  84.7 kB       0  [emitted]  app
   bundles/vendors.js  2.55 MB       1  [emitted]  vendors
chunk    {0} bundles/app.bundle.js (app) 89 kB {1} [rendered]
    [0] multi app 28 bytes {0} [built]
     + 26 hidden modules
chunk    {1} bundles/vendors.js (vendors) 2.45 MB [rendered]
    [0] multi vendors 148 bytes {1} [built]
     + 626 hidden modules
```

See, no bundles :( If I understood well, the third loader in `webpack.config.js` should take care of files imported in .js files and make them into `chunks`, so they could be loaded `dynamically (and lazily)`.

Additionally, my pages don't load. If I take out the code splitting out of the picture, it works :

```
render((
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={MainContent}>
      <IndexRoute component={Index} />
      <Route path="short-offers" getComponent={ShortOffers} />
      <Route path="create-job-offer" getComponent={CreateJobOffer} />
    </Route>
    <Route path="login" getComponent={LoginPage} />
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('content'));
```

But, my app is gonna be huge and I absolutely need code-splitting.

Would anyone please have a piece of insight to give me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Article author here. Try just running `npm start` (runs dev server) or `webpack -c webpack.config.js` (outputs files to `__build__` directory). I think you just forgot to point webpack at the correct config file.

Comment: Hello, thanks but I only have one webpack.config.js file... I tried anyway, but without luck. I've adopted the original React's huge app example's way since, thanks anyways!

Comment: Hello. I have no choice but to implement your way into my code (which is cool because I love the declarative way of the JSX). I updated my code, could you please take a look? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

use `module.exports` instead of `export default`

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';

const MainContent = (props) => (
    <div>
      <h1>App</h1>
      <ul>
        <li><Link to="/login">Login</Link></li>
      </ul>
      {props.children}
    </div>
);

MainContent.propTypes = {
  children: React.PropTypes.node.isRequired,
};

module.exports = MainContent;
```

or it's better to use `babel-plugin-add-module-exports` plugin it will transform

```
// index.js 
export default 'foo'
```

into

```
'use strict';
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});
exports.default = 'foo';
```